# Prove tha validity of the formula

Tags: first-order-logic

I came across this question in my assignment:

> For each of the following formulas, either prove that it is valid or give a counterexample to its validity.
>
> (a) ((∃xP(x)) ⊃ Q(a)) ⊃ (∀x(P(x) ⊃ Q(a)))
>
> (b) [∀x(P(x) ⊃ Q(a))] ⊃ [∃x(P(x)) ⊃ Q(a)]

I'm assuming that the first formula is not valid while the other one is valid. But how do I prove it and what kind of counterexample do I provide in order to show that a formula is not valid?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Also, For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Both formulae are *valid*; thus, you cannot find counter-examples.

For the proof, see Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic (2nd - 2001)](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA121) , page 122.

Comment: Thank you Mauro for the response.
I couldn't find the proof for these formulas in the book you mentioned. Maybe because it's just a preview of the book so I couldn't read further than page 123.

Comment: @FDebeyan - the proof is bottom page 121 - top page 122.